# im getting connection errors in my python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, error-handling

u have tried to run my program , but each time im getting error in the middile of the run 
basiclly, my program does this :
1. get the xml from my website
2. run all the urls
3. get data from my web page (sku,name,title, price etc)
4. get the lowest price from another website, by compraring the price with the same sku

the problem is that i have more then 7,000 urls in my xml ,so my program get error network each time 
what to do ? how can i resolve it ?

```
def parse_sitemap (url):
resp = requests.get(XXXX)
for u in urls:
    loc = u.find ('loc').string
    # not a sitemap requirement skip if not present
    out.append ([loc])
    return out
    def get_sku (u):
html = requests.get(u)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'xml')
sku = bsObj.find('span',attrs={'itemprop':'sku'}).get_text()
return sku
def get_price ( u):
    try:
        html = requests.get(u)
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'xml')
        price = bsObj.find('span',attrs={'itemprop':'price'}).get_text()
        price = str(price).replace(' ₪‎','')
        return price
    except:
        return 'no price'
    def get_zapPrice (makat):
try:
    check ='https://www.zap.co.il/search.aspx?keyword='+makat
    r = requests.get(check)
    html = requests.get(r.url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')
    zapPrice = bsObj.select_one('div.StoresLines div.PriceNum').text.strip().replace(' ₪','')
    return zapPrice
except:
    return 'no zap product'

   def get_zapStoreName (makat):
try:
    check ='https://www.zap.co.il/search.aspx?keyword='+makat
    r = requests.get(check)
    html = requests.get(r.url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')
    storeName = bsObj.select_one('div.StoresLines 
    div.BuyButtonsTxt').text.strip().replace('ב-','')
    return storeName
except:
    return 'no zap product'

for u in urls:
        ws1 [ 'A1' ] = u
        makat = get_sku(u)
        ws1 [ 'F1' ] = makat
        zapPrice = get_zapPrice(makat)
        ws1['I1'] = zapPrice
        storeName = get_zapStoreName(makat)
        ws1['J1'] = storeName
        ws1.insert_rows(1)
        ws1.append ([])
        print("writing product no." + str(i))
ws1['F1'] = 'makat'
ws1['I1'] = 'zap price'
ws1['J1'] = 'zap store'
wb.save ("sample.xlsx")
wb.close ()
print ('end')
```

i didn't write all my code - by the basic is here 
each def it's start with requests.get, get what i want and return it
after that, i'm writing it to excel file

the problem that im getting after 1,000 urls checks ... 
what is the problem ??

Comment: Please add the _complete_ error traceback.  It isn't possible to attempt to answer your question without knowing the exact problem.